# Flutter, how to handle keyboard shortcuts

Tags: flutter, keyboard, shortcut

wanna implement keyboard shortcuts into web app, found this example but it doesn't work as expected.

Would like action to occur every time I hold down alt and then press key A, though action occurs only when I press key alt and key A at the same time

thank

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyIntent extends Intent {}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  int integer = 0;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Shortcuts(
        shortcuts: {
          LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.alt, LogicalKeyboardKey.keyA):
              MyIntent(),
        },
        child: Actions(
          actions: {
            MyIntent: CallbackAction(onInvoke: (i) {
              print('rocks!!!' '$integer');
              integer++;
              return null;
            }),
          },
          child: Focus(
            autofocus: true,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 200,
              width: 500,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text('List of Homework'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the following way:  `SingleActivator(LogicalKeyboardKey.keyA, alt: true)`